# Create Workflow without criteria

Tags: workflow, record, entry-criteria

I am facing problem with my serial no. for records. When there is no record created due to some errors, that record also gets a count and I'm unable to get an uniform serial count. What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Select any one of  ***created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria*** OR ***created, and every time it's edited***  options and in ***Run rule in the*** Select formula evaluate true then in formula section write **True**

See the screenshot for your reference

[image]

Comment: Tried this way, not helping.

Comment: What issue you are facing?